# Am I using Boxes Package Correctly?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to convert CSV files into a table using the Boxes package
.
I am using IHaskell (Jupyter notebook extension) to do data analysis and would like to include nice looking tables. I could write a program to convert the CSV to a Jupyter markdown native table but that's not as fluid a process as generating the table on the fly.

Below is the code which produces a reasonable looking table but I had to do some manual stuff which made me think I wasn't using Boxes correctly.

There doesn't appear to be a way to set a fixed width Box (with padding) and the actual data centered within it. It's easy to get it to center the data but the box width is dependent on the width of the data resulting in a 'jagged' column.

My complicated code is below .. I've been doing Haskell for awhile but I still consider myself a novice.

Any comments greatly appreciated.

Tom

```
module Main (main) where

{-
  Notes:

    - This converst a CSV into a table
    - Am I using the Boxes package but I had to do a lot
      of work, using only punctuateH, punctuateV from the
      package.

    - Is there a better way to do it?

    - Things I had to do 'manually'
        - Center the data in a fixed width box. If I didn't
          do this the columns would not align since the data
          has various widths.
        - Add the outside borders

    - The input is rows of data separated by commas .. (CSV)

          on,pinput,pout,eff,ledi
          5.0e-6,8.43764e-2,7.88486e-2,0.934486,8.63554e-3
          5.4e-5,3.04731,2.90032,0.951765,0.214559
          1.03e-4,6.34257,6.03162,0.950973,0.434331

    - Produces,

   |--------------------------------------------------------------|
   |    on     |   pinput   |    pout    |     eff    |    ledi   |
   | ------------------------------------------------------------ |
   |  5.0e-6   | 8.43764e-2 | 7.88486e-2 |  0.934486  | 8.63554e-3|
   | ------------------------------------------------------------ |
   |  5.4e-5   |   3.04731  |   2.90032  |  0.951765  |  0.214559 |
   | ------------------------------------------------------------ |
   |  1.03e-4  |   6.34257  |   6.03162  |  0.950973  |  0.434331 |
   |--------------------------------------------------------------|


-}

import Text.PrettyPrint.Boxes

replace :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replace a b = map $ \c -> if c == a then b else c

setLen :: Int -> String -> String
setLen n str =
  let fullPad = n - (length str)
      halfPadLen = truncate $ (fromIntegral fullPad) / (2.0::Double)
      halfPad = replicate halfPadLen ' '
  in
     if (even fullPad)
        then halfPad        ++ str ++ halfPad
        else halfPad ++ " " ++ str ++ halfPad                  
      
padEnds :: String -> String
padEnds str =
  let theLines = lines str
      tableW = (length (head theLines)) + 2
      allData =  concatMap (\aLine -> "|" ++ aLine ++ "|\n") theLines
      bar = replicate (tableW-2) '-'
  in "|" ++ bar ++ "|\n" ++ allData ++ "|" ++ bar ++ "|\n" 
  

renderTable :: String -> String
renderTable str = toStr ( lines (replace ',' ' ' str) )
    
  where
    toStr :: [String] -> String
    toStr theLines =
      let allBoxes = map (\aLine -> makeBoxes aLine) theLines
          hs = map (\row -> punctuateH center1 (text " | ") row) allBoxes 
          box = punctuateV center1 (text (replicate 60 '-'))  hs
          rawStr = render box
      in padEnds rawStr

    makeBoxes :: String -> [Box]
    makeBoxes aLine =
       let sameLen = map (setLen 10) (words aLine)
       in map text sameLen

     
main :: IO ()
main = do
  fileData <- readFile "test2.csv"
  putStrLn $ renderTable fileData
```

Comment: Ages ago I wrote a prototype for an extension that displays nice-looking tables directly from simple Haskell types (tuples / lists), which could also be used easily with data coming from CSV. https://github.com/leftaroundabout/IHaskell-tables I don't use it, or IHaskell generally, anymore though.

Comment: Thanks! This could solve the issue .. If I can get it integrated. Any reason you don't use IHaskell anymore?

Comment: https://github.com/leftaroundabout/IHaskell-tables/pull/2#issuecomment-962452638

Comment: Thanks again !  I use IHaskell/Jupyter for two purposes .. A sort of notebook for learning Haskell (nothing like playing with Monads on Sunday afternoon :-) ), and documenting electronic circuit design projects - the Haskell part allows me to graph simulations, and show design equations (and share them) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think you're using boxes wrong. Here's what my go would look like:

```
import Prelude hiding ((<>)) -- ugh
import Data.List
import Text.PrettyPrint.Boxes

table :: [[String]] -> Box
table sss = border <> punctuateH center1 sep cs <> border where
    border = vtext (replicate height '|')
    sep = vtext (take height (cycle "-|"))
    height = maxPosOn rows cs
    cs = map column (transpose sss)

column :: [String] -> Box
column ss = sep // punctuateV center1 sep (map text ss) // sep where
    sep = text (replicate (maxPosOn length ss+2) '-')

vtext :: String -> Box
vtext = vcat center1 . map char

maxPosOn :: (a -> Int) -> [a] -> Int
maxPosOn f = maximum . (0:) . map f
```

Try it out in ghci:

```
> printBox $ table [["on","pinput","pout","eff","ledi"],["5.0e-6","8.43764e-2","7.88486e-2","0.934486","8.63554e-3"],["5.4e-5","3.04731","2.90032","0.951765","0.214559"],["1.03e-4","6.34257","6.03162","0.950973","0.434331"]]
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|    on   |   pinput   |    pout    |   eff    |    ledi    |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|  5.0e-6 | 8.43764e-2 | 7.88486e-2 | 0.934486 | 8.63554e-3 |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|  5.4e-5 |  3.04731   |  2.90032   | 0.951765 |  0.214559  |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
| 1.03e-4 |  6.34257   |  6.03162   | 0.950973 |  0.434331  |
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Daniel, Thanks for all the effort!  Now *this* looks like it's really using the Boxes package. Once I digest it I think Boxes will be a nice addition to my toolkit .. Thanks again!